# Undestanding how cartesian product implementation on Haskell works

Tags: haskell, cartesian-product

I have started learning Haskell and I have problem with understanding how cartesian product of  lists of the list works

here is the supposed code

```
cprod = foldr f [[ ]]
      where f xs yss = foldr g [ ] xs
            where g x zss = foldr h zss yss
                  where h ys uss = (x : ys) : uss
```

What exactly I don't get is the last function 
I've replaced variable names as I understand it

```
mycart = foldr f [[]]
    where f currentresult listelem = foldr g [] currentresult
          where g currentresultonstep currentresultelem = foldr h currentresultelem listelem
                where h currentresultelemonstep onelistelem = (currentresultonstep:currentreslteleemonstep):onelistelem
```

Shouldn't the last string be something like this?

```
where h currentresultelemonstep onelistelem = (onelistelem:currentresultelemonstep):currentresultonstep
```

as we try to add the elements of the list to the beginning on elements of current result
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your code as written isn't syntactically valid:

```
foo.hs:3:13: parse error on input `where'
```

Second, it seems like you're confused about the order of arguments in the first parameter of `foldr`:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

The first argument (`a`) is an element of the input list (`[a]`), the second argument (`b`) is the accumulator.

Comment: when I write 'where f x y', for foldr , y - is accumulator?

Comment: Yes, and x is the current element.

Comment: Because it's the other way around for `foldl`.